# wp_redirect & header re-directs prevent me from using Wordpress functions

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

None of the functions in my functions.php file work after I perform a redirect.

To be more specific, what I have done is use a first php file to do an inital API call, write an array into a txt file, then redirects to another php file that starts off by reading the txt file and then making another API call based on the array of the first. Then parsing that data, and putting it into a wp database in a certain format.

I know that the problem lies with the re-direct because I have tested multiple scenarios as can be seen below and they all point to the re-direct being the culprit.

For example,  on my first php file I have the below.

```
if (function_exists('is_wp_version')){
    echo "is_wp_version exists!! <br>";
} else {
    echo "is_wp_version, it does not exist <br>";
}


if (function_exists('fopen')){
    echo "fopen exists!! <br>";
} else {
    echo "fopen, it does not exist <br>";
}

... More code...
... More code...

wp_redirect( 'PHPfile2.php', 301 ); exit; // I have also tried the header 
//function with same results
?>
```

And I will always see printed the below output if I comment out the redirect line .

```
is_wp_version exists!!
fopen exists!!
```

However, in PHPfile2.php, I always see the below and get some error and the below output.

```
is_wp_version, it does not exist
fopen exists!!

Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in PHPfile2.php on line 22
```

And it gives me some sort of Fatal error.  If I remove or comment out the code with the get_header function, then I get a Fatal error on the next wordpress function.

Can someone point me in the right direction?  Am I going about this the wrong way?  I just need to be able to do 2 API calls with the second dependent on what I get back from the first one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that you're leaving the wordpress framework and using your own custom files (which is highly inadvisable).

You need to `require_once('wp-blog-header.php');`. in `PHPfile2.php`.

Comment: Thank you for the insight.  I would use this only to add certain information from the API to my WP database.  It is not meant for visitors of the site to access these php files.  Is there a better way to do this?